# Turn on Nexus One without Power button

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-one, power-on, trackball

My Google Nexus One has a broken power button. I'm using **CyanogenMod-7.2.0-passion** on it. I would like to configure **trackball** to turn on my device (after battery died or after changing the SIM or SD card).

Are there any ways to configure the **trackball** as the default power switch instead of power switch on top of the phone?

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't possible. Some CM versions allow you to use the trackball to turn the screen on, but there's no way to turn the device on from cold this way. When the device is off, Android isn't running, so nothing in Android can listen for a button press. The handling of the power button is much lower-level in the device firmware, and isn't available for users to change.